# Incompatible input shape

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm, datashape

I have a **CNN-LSTM** model where the **CNN** model takes as input data with shape **(None, 301,4,1)** and outputs data with shape **(None, 606)**. To adapt the cnn output to the input of the **LSTM**, I added a TimeDistributed Layer where it call the CNN model each window-size=100, so the input shape of this layer=**(None, 100,301,4,1)**, and then we have some stacked **LSTM** layers.

This is the architecture of the **CNN** model:

[image]

This is the architecture of the **LSTM** model:

[image]

The code for this architecture is the following :

```py
input_layer1=Input(shape=(301,4,1)) 
... 
merge_layer=Concatenate(axis=1)([global_max_pooling, lambda_14]) 
cnn_model = Model(inputs=  input_layer1, outputs=merge_layer) cnn_model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),loss="mean_squared_error",metrics=['mse', 'mae'])

input_lstm = Input(shape=(100,301,4,1)) 
cnn_output = TimeDistributed(cnn_model)(input_lstm) 
... 
output_layer=Dense(1,activation="linear")(lstm3)     
cnn_lstm_model = Model(inputs= input_lstm, outputs=output_layer)
cnn_lstm_model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),loss="mean_squared_error",metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
```

Then saved only the cnn_lstm_model model.

For the training, this is my code:

```py
batchsize=100
epoch=20
cnn_lstm_model.fit(train_data_force_temp_X,data_Y,
               batch_size=batchsize,
               epochs=epoch,
               verbose=1,
               shuffle=True,
               validation_data=(test_data_force_temp_X,test_Y),
               callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir="./CNN_LSTM")])
```

Where train_data_force_temp_X.shape = (1960, 301, 4, 1)  , PS: 1960 is number of samples.

But I have this issue :

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected
> shape=(None, 100, 301, 4, 1), found shape=(None, 301, 4, 1)

I understood that passed the wrong shape to the cnn_lstm_model but I thought that it will pass the data first to the cnn model which have the shape=(None, 301, 4, 1) and then for each 100 CNN outputs it will call the time distributed layer and continue the process, It seems I have not understood the process correctly.

So my question is :

- do I have to run the data first into the cnn model, do prediction and
  then used those outputs as an input for the cnn_lstm model ?
- How can I fix the training process ?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: the input samples of cnn_lstm_model must have 100 timesteps otherwise there is no reason to apply CNN + TimeDistributed

Comment: @MarcoCerliani thank you for the response.  I know that cnn_lstm_model must have 100 timesteps, but what I understood from the time distribution layer is that it will call the cnn model 100 time and by doing that it will construct 100 timestep.  but I thing that  I am wrong, so do you have an idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Yes, the TimeDistributed call the cnn model 100 times along with the temporal dimensionality but it doesn't construct anything. You have to rearrange your data in order to have a temporal dimensionality otherwise remove the TimeDistributed layer